# Java Inheritance - this keyword

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, this

I searched online for similar question, but could not find it. So, posting here.

In the following program why the value of 'i' is printed as 100?

AFAIK 'this' refers to the current object; which in this case is 'TestChild' and the class name is also correctly printed. But why the value of the instance variable is not 200?

```
public class TestParentChild {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestChild().printName();
    }
}

class TestChild extends TestParent{
    public int i = 200;
}

class TestParent{
    public int i = 100;
    public void printName(){
        System.err.println(this.getClass().getName());
        System.err.println(this.i); //Shouldn't this print 200
    }
}
```

And moreover the output of the following is as i expected. The child class method is invoked, when i call "**this.test()**" from Parent class.

```
public class TestParentChild {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestChild().printName();
    }
}

class TestChild extends TestParent{
    public int i = 200;
    public void test(){
        System.err.println("Child Class : "+i);
    }

}

class TestParent{
    public int i = 100;
    public void printName(){
        System.err.println(this.getClass().getName());
        System.err.println(this.i); //Shouldn't this print 200
        this.test();
    }
    public void test(){
        System.err.println("Parent Class : "+i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does not have virtual fields, so the `i` field in `printName` always refers to `TestParent.i` and not any descendant child.

Polymorphism through inheritance in Java only happens with methods, so if you want the behaviour you're describing then you'd want this:

```
class TestChild extends TestParent{

    private int i = 200;

    @Override
    public int getI() { return this.i; }
}

class TestParent{

    private int i = 100;

    public int getI() { return this.i; }

    public void printName(){
        System.err.println( this.getClass().getName() );
        System.err.println( this.getI() ); // this will print 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Could you please eloberate, what do you mean by this? **"In Java fields cannot be marked as virtual"** As i mentioned, in my second program the instance method is invoked correctly. But instance variable is referring to the Parent class.

Comment: In Java, all methods (unless specified) are "virtual", which means they have an associated vtable which allows for runtime dispatch. Fields, however, exist as an absolute-(ish) memory location and are not offset by any vtable. I blame the confusion on Java's design document which doesn't have explicit "virtual" and "override" keywords whereas C# does.

Comment: one more question. Java specification says **this** refers to the current object, which is instance of TestChild in this case. That's the reason when i call **this.test()**, it invokes the method from child class. But when i say **this.i** how does Java interpret **this** keyword?

Comment: @user1790274 Basically, your object has two completely separate versions of `i`: `TestChild.i` and `TestParent.i`. Forget the fact that they both look like the variable `i`, they're totally separate. When a method uses `i`, Java looks for the most specific version it can find. For a method defined in TestChild, that's `TestChild.i`, and similarly for TestParent. The term for this, btw, is "shadowing," and it can be a source of confusing bugs (as you found!). Best solution is to always use private variables, so that there's no reason to expect that `this.i` would ever be a parent's `i`.

Comment: (sorry, got too long for one comment) This behavior is different for methods, because Java's methods are virtual as @Dai pointed out. That is, you (essentially, with some handwaving for now) only have _one_ version of the `test()` method, and the child's `test()` replaces the parent's. So basically, methods are replaced via inheritance, whereas variables are not and instead create two separate, confusingly-named variables.

Answer (score 2):

Because fields in Java aren't inherited. Using your declarations, you have effectively declared two *different* fields named `i`, and instances of `TestChild` will have both. When `TestParent` is compiled, references to `i` in its methods will always refer to `TestParent.i`.

Comment: Fields are inherited, just not overridden.

Comment: Sure, that is better phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to override a class variable.

You do not override class variables in Java, instead you hide them. Overriding is for instance methods and hiding is different from overriding.

In the example you've given, by declaring the class variable with the name 'i' in class `TestChild` you hide the class variable it would have inherited from its superclass `TestParent` with the same name 'i'. Hiding a variable in this way does not affect the value of the class variable 'i' in the superclass `TestParent`

To get the desired behavior, you can just override the `getI()` method

```
class TestChild extends TestParent{

    private int i = 200;

    @Override
    public int getI() {
         return this.i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had read about hiding (shadowing), but forgot about it. :( Thanks again.